# Extracting text from title tag the adding as id lower case and space with - for div using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

Is it possible that extracting text from title tag in task and adding as id to div tag id as small letters spaces with -

my input xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<topic>
<task>
<title class="- topic/title ">Working with new XML</title>
<taskbody class="- topic/body  task/taskbody ">
<section class="- topic/section ">
<title class="- topic/title ">Settings IVN</title>
<p class="- topic/p ">Repository location http:/google.com/heights</p>
</section>  
</taskbody>
</task>
<task>
<title class="- topic/title ">Clearing the Content</title>
<taskbody class="- topic/body  task/taskbody ">
<section class="- topic/section ">
<title class="- topic/title ">Delete the contents</title>
<p class="- topic/p ">From local directory</p>
</section>  
</taskbody>
</task>
</topic>
```

I have used the XSL as:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:output method="xml"
              encoding="UTF-8"
              indent="no"
              />
<xsl:variable name="convert" select="//task/title[@class='- topic/title ']"/>
<xsl:variable name="inputval" select="translate($convert, ' ', '_')"/>
<xsl:variable name="convert1" select="//section/title[@class='- topic/title ']"/>
<xsl:variable name="inputval1" select="translate($convert1, ' ', '_')"/>
<xsl:template match="task">
<xsl:text>
</xsl:text>
<div class="topic" id="{$inputval}">
<xsl:apply-templates/>
</div>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="task/title">
<h1>
<xsl:apply-templates/></script></h1>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="topic">
<html>
<body>
<xsl:apply-templates/>
<body>
</html>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="section">
<div>
<div class="section" id="{$inputval1}">
<xsl:apply-templates/>
</div>
</div>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="title">
<h2 class="sectiontitle">
<xsl:apply-templates/>
</h2>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="p">
<p>
<xsl:apply-templates/>
</p>    
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

output i am getting first title id format repeated and id produced as:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<html>
<body>
<div class="topic" id="Working_with_new_XML">
<h1>Working with new XML</h1>
<div>
<div class="section" id="Settings_IVN">
<h2 class="sectiontitle">Settings IVN</h2>
<p>Repository location http:/google.com/heights</p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="topic" id="Working_with_new_XML">
<h1>Clearing the Content</h1>
<div>
<div class="section" id="Settings_IVN">
<h2 class="sectiontitle">Delete the contents</h2>
<p>From local directory</p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Required output as id as particular title as small letters and space as - and id not repeated as like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<html>
<body>
<div class="topic" id="working_with_new_xml">
<h1>Working with new XML</h1>
<div>
<div class="section" id="settings_ivn">
<h2 class="sectiontitle">Settings IVN</h2>
<p>Repository location http:/google.com/heights</p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="topic" id="clearing_the_content">
<h1>Clearing the Content</h1>
<div>
<div class="section" id="delete_the_contents">
<h2 class="sectiontitle">Delete the contents</h2>
<p>From local directory</p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Please assist me.

Comment: Your stylesheet does not compile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define two variables as:

```
<xsl:variable name="source-chars" select="'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ '"/>
<xsl:variable name="target-chars" select="'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz_'"/>
```

and use them as:

```
<xsl:template match="task">
    <div class="topic" id="{translate(title, $source-chars, $target-chars   )}">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </div>
</xsl:template>
```

and:

```
<xsl:template match="section">
    <div>
        <div class="section" id="{translate(title, $source-chars, $target-chars )}">
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </div>
    </div>
</xsl:template>
```

---

P.S. I don't  think you need the 4 variables you have in your stylesheet.